# ngClass if statement multiple expressions not working

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class

I would like to give the the class 'bg-green' to the div when 'task.taskChecked' is true. This works, and also when 'task.taskDescription' has the word 'afspraak' the class should be 'bg-purple' this also works.

But with what I am struggling is, when 'task.taskChecked'is true AND 'task.taskDescription' contains the word 'afspraak' also give it the class 'bg-green'

Here is the code:

```
<div class="tableCell taskIndicator" data-ng-class="{'bg-green': task.taskChecked == true || ( task.taskChecked == true && task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1 ), 'bg-red': task.taskChecked == false, 'bg-purple': task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1}">

</div>
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
<div class="tableCell taskIndicator" data-ng-class="{'bg-green': task.taskChecked, 'bg-red': task.taskChecked == false, 'bg-purple': task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1&&!task.taskChecked}">

</div>
```

Comment: Why have you used an OR || ( task.taskChecked == true && task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1 ) condition?

Comment: `task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1` this condition evaluates to true in both cases, `bg-green` and `bg-purple`, and angular applies the last class specified to your element.

Comment: You can try 'bg-green': task.taskChecked &&!(task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1)

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work.. What I am trying to achieve is, that when the object has task.taskChecked true and also the task.taskDescription contains 'afspraak' the class is 'bg-green'.

Comment: Then try 'bg-purple': task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1&&!task.taskChecked" and 'bg-green': task.taskChecked

Comment: Thank you this works! :)

Answer (score 0):

order is important while writing your expression.

```
<div class="tableCell taskIndicator"  data-ng-class="{'bg-red':
task.taskChecked == false, 'bg-purple':
task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1,
'bg-green': task.taskChecked == true || ( task.taskChecked == true &&
task.taskDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf('afspraak') > -1 )}">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I am trying to achieve is, that when the object has task.taskChecked true and also the task.taskDescription contains 'afspraak' the class is 'bg-green' but instead now it still gives it the class 'bg-purple'.

Comment: Thanks for replying! But it is no longer necessary!